# How to execute streaming-static join faster than normal to be in sync with batch trigger duration?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v to streaming in my PoC.

I have a scenario as below
Dataset staticDf = // previous data from hdfs/cassandra table
Dataset streamingDf = // data from kafka topic for streaming

```
Dataset<Row> joinDs =   streamingDs.join(staticDs, streamingDs.col("companyId").equalTo(staticDs.col("company_id"), "inner"));
```

Even though this is working fine I have an issue with timings of the join.
Currently my streaming Tigger time is around 10 seconds. Where are this join been run for almost 1 min.  So I am not getting the results in the expected time.

How can I make my join trigger at for every 10 seconds ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, to perform join Spark needs to read all data from Cassandra, and this is slow. As I mentioned before, you need to use DSE Analytics if you want to perform efficient join on the Dataset/Dataframe, or use `joinWithCassandra`/`leftJoinWithCassandra` from RDD API.

Update in September 2020th: support for join with Cassandra in dataframes was added in the [Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all)

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12